# Symmetry of the hamiltonian $H = \frac{1}{2m}p^2 + V(r) + a \, \vec{s} \cdot \vec{l} $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, symmetry, group-theory, hamiltonian

Consider the hamiltonian
\begin{align}
H& = H_0 + a\, \vec{s} \cdot \vec{l} 
\\& = \frac{1}{2m}p^2+ V(r) + a\, \vec{s} \cdot \vec{l},
\end{align}
where $V(r)$ denotes an arbitrary central potential.

What is the symmetry of this hamiltonian? $\rm SU(2)$ or $\rm SO(3)$? Without the spin-orbit coupling part (or even the spin-degree of freedom), the symmetry of $H_0 $ should be $\rm SO(3)$, right?

I suspect that it is $\rm SU(2)$, but cannot prove it.

Answer (score 2):

$SU(2)$. Indeed,  the  set of the 3  spin-operator components is affected by the same spatial rotation as the ones  of the angular momentum operator when $SU(2)$ acts and the scalar product between the two (triples of) operators  is rotationally invariant.
The rest of the total Hamiltonian is rotationally invariant so that it is both $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ invariant.

It is actually disputable if a $SU(2)$ symmetry exists at all (referring to physical space transformations). Since symmetries are always projective from the Wigner theorem  and one  cannot distinguish between the action of $SO(3)$ and that of $SU(2)$ on pure states (unit vectors up to phases).